# HTML highlighting in ATOM dysfunctional when using ZURB Foundation Template Engine Syntax

Tags: syntax-highlighting, atom-editor

Im new to ZURB Foundation 6 and its Foundation CLI. Using the template engine works like a charm though, except for the syntax highlighting so far.

Here is a screenshot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDq1k.jpg

As you can see, highlighting the beginning and end of an HTML Element doesnt work anymore when Im using the template engine syntax with the double brackets. The site works perfectly, so this erroneous interpretation of the HTML structure is a problem of the editor. 
Is there any way to work around this issue in ATOM? Or do I have to live with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're using a templating engine such as Handlebars (which ZURB [seems to use](https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/panini.html)), you need to install a language syntax for that. There are [several available](https://atom.io/packages/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=handlebars+syntax), you need to find out for yourself which one works best for you.

Once installed, you either need to work with `.hbs` files for automatic detection, or you have to specify the syntax manually by clicking on the dialog that reads "HTML" on your screenshot (in the bottom right).